# BlueJ Chpt 4 - Auction Project - How to make removeLot method work after entering a new lot

Tags: java

I am learning Java through BlueJ

I would like to add a removeLot method to the Auction Class in BlueJ Chpt 4. This involves also returning the lot with the given number or null if there is no such lot.

If you enter , say 5 lots and then use the remove method, this codes removes whichever lot you specify.  However if you enter a new  lot after using the removeLot method - an   internal error message comes up regarding lotnumbering .

Any ideas?

Thanks
Elaine

```
public Lot removeLot(int number) {
    if((number >= 1)) {           

    }
    Lot lot = getLot(number);
    if(lot != null) {
        lots.remove(lot);
    }
    return lot;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo in your code (or formatting spoiled something). The method probably should be:

```
public Lot removeLot(int number) {
    Lot lot = null;
    if((number >= 1)) {
        lot = getLot(number);
    }
    if(lot != null) {
        lots.remove(lot);
    }
    return lot;
}
```

I tested it with the following code and it worked ok:

```
Auction a = new Auction();
a.enterLot("a1");
a.enterLot("a2");
a.enterLot("a3");
a.showLots();
a.removeLot(3);
a.showLots();
a.enterLot("a4");
a.showLots();
```

The output was:

```
1: a1    (No bid)
2: a2    (No bid)
3: a3    (No bid)
1: a1    (No bid)
2: a2    (No bid)
1: a1    (No bid)
2: a2    (No bid)
4: a4    (No bid)
```

Comment: Hi Piotr

Thanks so much for your help. Your code works but I cannot use the getLot method for newly entered lots or make a bid on the newly entered lots after the removeLot method has ben used  Elaine